# Is there a way to use multiple docker registry proxy in cluster?

Tags: docker, registry

My fellow mates and I encountered in a situation in which we'd like to have one computer with an internet connection (will be referred as HOST 1) to proxy multiple registries to few computers without internet connection (will be referred as CHILD HOST) but with a direct connection to HOST 1.

[Registries Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYoS1.png)

General requirements

1. We'd like to pull images from dockerhub without any prefix (e.g. `docker pull ubuntu` and not `docker pull localregistry:<someport>/ubuntu`)
2. We'd like the local registry in HOST 1 to cache downloaded images from **every registry**
3. We'd like to be able to pull from multiple registries

   1. From docker hub - `docker pull ubuntu`
   2. From registry1 - `docker pull registry1.dns/nameofimage`
   3. From registry2 - `docker pull registry2.dns/nameofimage`

What we have tried so far:

1. Docker private registry - we installed a docker private registry and added it to registry mirror, the disadvantages are that the private registry can only mirror one registry.
   in order to cache & enable CHILD HOSTS to pull also docker hub images, we changed docker HTTP_PROXY to be the private registry, this led that we can only proxy 1 registry at a time.
2. Sonatype Nexus3 - we created proxy registries for docker-hub, registry1 and registry2. then we grouped them into nexus docker group and added the group registry to docker mirror registry, the disadvantages are that we weren't able to pull images from docker hub with `docker pull ubuntu`, we had to pull with `docker pull <nexus3address>:<docker group port>/ubuntu` of course that didn't work for us either.
3. We had tried to use https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/docker-registry-proxy as well and we encountered the same issues as the above (required prefix for docker pull)

Any ideas?